# How can I launch soft phoneType keyboard with numbers 0 to 9 and a + in it programatically in android?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-inputtype

I have a DialogFragment which has two EditText views. One takes email and another takes phone number of a friend. These two may be filled with a contact from contacts (I have a button that takes to contact picker). I am able to show the keyboard right after launching the fragment with this when focus is on email view by default :

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

I want to launch soft keyboard with digits 0 - 9 programatically (same like when we touch edittext of phone inputType). What I did is that when user pick contact, it fills the email (contact has only email, say) then I have set focus to phone view using requestFocus() which worked and I see the cursor is moved to phone view. Then I called the above code to show but that did not work. I could find any other way on net too.

Any clue ?

Comment: Usually you use a edittext with inputType numbers to do that.

Comment: Yes, @Nanoc is right. Just move the focus to the second EditText view and show the kbd.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that your keyboard appears upon an [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html). 
So, the only thing that you have to do to trigger arithmetic keyboard is to declare in your EditText the [InputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) as number.

```
<EditText android:inputType="number"/>
```

and the InputManager stays as you have declared it.

Comment: Will this have the plus symbol add well to be able to enter the complete phone number? Not at my system to quick test.

Comment: Also how you make it 'upon editext'? Using requestFocus () ? That didn't launch the phoneType keyboard. That's what I mentioned clearly.